# Trigger in SQL causing error "Product_Reorder is not a recognized SET option"

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER CheckQuantity
ON dbo.Products 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Products
    SET Product_ReOrder = 1 
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE i.Product_ID = dbo.Products.Product_ID
      AND i.Product_QOH < 5;
```

I am not getting a syntax error

> syntax error near ;

This is referring to the `;` at the end of the code.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Triggers are highly vendor-specific so you would need to *tag* your database. That said, what you have shown is in no way valid SQL in any dialect.

Comment: Ok I added the tag

Comment: Stu, it's clearly not valid SQL that's why I need help.

Comment: Your specific error is because `set` is not how you *update* rows in SQL Server or any RDBMS; to update values you use `update table set <columns>`, however what you have described in your question is not really enough to go on to be sure of your expectations; I would recommend working through a [trigger tutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do - you're not giving us much to go on, either!

I'm **assuming** you mean you want to set a **column** called `Product_ReOrder` in your table to 1 if another column `Product_QOH` is less than 5 - correct?

In that case - use a trigger something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER CheckQuantity
ON dbo.Products 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Products
    SET Product_ReOrder = 1 
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE i.PrimaryKeyColumn = dbo.Products.PrimaryKeyColumn
      AND i.Product_QOH < 5;
END
```

The trigger will fire after an `UPDATE`, and `Inserted` will contain **all** rows (can and **will** be multiple rows!) that have been updated - so I'm assuming you want to check the quantity on those rows.

I'm joining the base table (`dbo.Products`) to the `Inserted` pseudo table on the primary key column of your table (which we don't know what it is - so you need to adapt this as needed), and I'm setting the `Product_ReOrder` column to 1, if the `Products_QOH` value is less than 5.

Your line of code

```
Select @QOH = (select Product_QOH from inserted)
```

has a **fatal flaw** of assuming that only one row was updated - this might be the case sometimes - but you cannot **rely** on that! Your trigger **must be capable** of handling multiple rows being updated - because the trigger is called only **once**, even if 10 rows are updated with a command - and then `Inserted` will contain all those 10 updated rows. Doing such a select is dangerous - you'll get *one arbitrary* row, and you'll ignore all the rest of them ....

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: So what I need to do is set up a trigger that updates Product_Reorder which is a bit to 1 when Products_QOH is less than 5. When I used this code it is giving me incorrect Syntax near the "5;"

Comment: @TassoPsaltakis: sorry - had a typo (extra "s" at the end of `Products_QOH` - appears to be `Product_QOH` - try my updated trigger. It's a bit **confusing** because you had **both spelling** (with and without an "s" at the end) in your question......

Comment: I also see in the code you mention Primary keys however I do not have any keys within this table

Comment: @TassoPsaltakis: every table **ought to have** a primary key!

Comment: Am I supposed to have keys on this table? Is there any way for this to be done without having to use a PrimaryKey? I just need to check the value of one column then update the other.

Comment: What do you suggest I make the primary key for then? Or how should I make it LOL

Comment: @TassoPsaltakis: you need a **primary key** to uniquely identify a row in a table - and you need this in order for this trigger to work.

Comment: Im sorry for being so hard to work with I am really lost.

Comment: Well, is there **any** column in your table that would **uniquely** and reliably identify a single row? Is there something like a `ProductId` or something? It would be great help if you'd post the **structure** of the table you're working with - column names, datatypes, any constraints and keys on the table .....

Comment: Please - do **NOT** add a screenshot! Post the `CREATE TABLE` statement **as properly formatted text** instead!

Comment: wait there is a product code! I will make this. the primary key

Comment: Ok recreated the entire table and made a column Product_ID and made that a primary key. When I include it into the code you gave me 'where i.Product_ID = dbo.Product_ID' I am getting a syntax error

Comment: @TassoPsaltakis _I am getting a syntax error_ is NEVER a useful thing to write. And comments are not intended for adding additional code and details about your problem. In addition, it is difficult to guess what you actually wrote as code and how it was executed / tested. Quite simply, you need more help than can be provided in a technical Q&A forum like SO. You need to master tsql before you attempt triggers. And designing databases is a very different skill from writing tsql - which is something else you need to learn.

Comment: Bro I am literally In school to learn it. This is for an assignment I figured out I needed to add the 'end'. I am a student and to be quite honest Marc was very helpful. I don't need you "need to learn how to do this" because clearly, I don't know how to do it. Thank you marc I appreciate your help. As for you SMor, clearly, If I mastered something wouldn't be asking a question would I?

Comment: @TassoPsaltakis Side point: no you don't *need* to add the `END` you can instead remove the `BEGIN`. It is unnecessary and only serves to confuse the fact that the *whole batch* is the procedure (up until `GO` if you use SSMS)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear what you were thinking when you wrote this code, or what template you were basing off, but **there are many syntax errors**.

It seems you probably want something like this:

- The `update()` function only tells us if that column was present in the `update` statement, not if anything was actually changed.
- We need to check if we are being called recursively, in order to bail out.
- We also check if no rows have been changed at all, and bail out early
- Note how `inserted` and `deleted` are compared to see if any rows actually changed. This also deals correctly with multiple rows.
- We then need to rejoin `Products` in order to update it.

```sql
create or alter trigger CheckQuantity
on Products 
after update
as
    set nocount on;

    if not(update(Products_QOH))
       or TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID, 'AFTER', 'DML') > 1
       or not exists (select 1 from inserted)
         return;  -- early bail-out

    update p
    set Product_ReOrder = 1
    from Products p
    join (
        select i.YourPrimaryKey, i.Products_QOH
        from inserted i
        where i.Product_QOH < 5
        except
        select d.YourPrimaryKey, d.Products_QOH
        from deleted d
    ) i on i.YourPrimaryKey = p.YourPrimaryKey;
```

---

**However, I don't understand why you are using a trigger at all.**

I strongly suggest you use a computed column for this instead:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Products
    DROP COLUMN Product_ReOrder;

ALTER TABLE Products
    ADD Product_ReOrder AS (CASE WHEN Product_QOH < 5 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END);
```

Comment: I need to use a trigger. ITs for an assignment. We are supposed to be using a table that doesn't have any keys. I just need to get the value of one column and then update the other column.

Comment: If you have a table with no keys then you need to rethink your schema. If that is what you were given I suggest you speak to your teacher about the necessity of proper database normalization