# I'm creating this trigger in SQL, but at the end of execution, when I enter more than one data, it changes all CPF's, how to solve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm creating this trigger in SQL, but at the end of execution, when I enter more than one data, it changes all CPF's, how to solve?

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_Limpa_Cpf
ON tbl_Cobranca
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE 
    @CPF VARCHAR (14),
    @CPF_Valido VARCHAR (11)

    SELECT @CPF = CPF FROM INSERTED
        SELECT @CPF_Valido = REPLACE(REPLACE(@CPF,'.', ''),'-', '')
            UPDATE tbl_Cobranca set CPF = @CPF_Valido


END
GO
```

When I run the insert into, like the ones below, it sets in the CPF column of the 10 entries, the last CPF. What do I do?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '600.599.013-49',146024000,742.66, '19/07/2019 ' ,1, ' 62085637761 '  , 'Inativo ', 'Devolvido ', ' 30/03/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,250,NULL,2, ' Lindseia Domingos Bacaicoa ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '347.275.181-20',23100372,1081.22, '18/03/2020 ' ,4, ' 61354685318 '  , 'Inativo ', 'Devolvido ', ' 08/04/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,30,NULL,2, ' Antonio Gaetano Franco ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '375.416.474-28',10062872,1235.58, '22/08/2019 ' ,2, ' 45569215172 '  , 'Ativo ', 'Ativo ', ' 01/04/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,336,NULL,1, ' Waldecy Aranha De Souza ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '620.421.024-25',9080169,709.78, '02/12/2018 ' ,5, ' 20637885865 '  , 'Ativo ', 'Ativo ', ' 01/04/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,599,NULL,1, ' Josiane Goncalves De Oliveira ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '587.715.716-59',12067127,568.84, '12/05/2020 ' ,13, ' 30940355198 '  , 'Ativo ', 'Ativo ', ' 01/04/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,72,NULL,1, ' Vandeir Pedro Goncalves ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '551.112.540-72',97169365,886.2, '07/05/2020 ' ,0, ' 75769424904 '  , 'Inativo ', 'Devolvido ', ' 28/05/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,29,NULL,2, ' Sergio Aparecido De Vasconcelos ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '544.877.944-08',148016204,649.23, '13/03/2020 ' ,3, ' 13896261143 '  , 'Inativo ', 'Devolvido ', ' 06/04/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,42,NULL,2, ' Jocelia Giboski ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '530.036.855-73',137014060,677.51, '17/02/2017 ' ,0, ' 63755063318 '  , 'Inativo ', 'Devolvido ', ' 30/03/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,1132,NULL,2, ' Carlos Roberto Toniolli ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '361.078.484-75',146025052,995.47, '19/03/2020 ' ,4, ' 43587796897 '  , 'Ativo ', 'Ativo ', ' 01/04/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,126, ' RENAULT ' ,1, ' Rosana De Fatima Mendonca ' )
INSERT INTO tbl_Cobranca VALUES ( '260.057.428-95',97140256,1043.69, '08/12/2019 ' ,5, ' 78098625396 '  , 'Ativo ', 'Ativo ', ' 01/04/2020 ' , ' PGMAIS ' ,228,NULL,1, ' Percilia Santos Do Amaral ' )
```

Comment: One problem is that `UPDATE tbl_Cobranca set CPF = @CPF_Valido` updates every record as there is no where clause. Does your table have a primary key? The other problem is that `inserted` has many rows

Comment: You don't even need a trigger for this, I suggest you use a calculated column instead

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  I'm new to this process, some way to make a trigger work multiple inserts at once? Or how could I make this column calculate? Yes, my table has a primary key.

Comment: Your trigger assumes your DML statement will only ever effect *exactly* 1 row; this isn't true. A DML statement can effect 0+ rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger in SQL causing error "Product\_Reorder is not a recognized SET option"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70147271/trigger-in-sql-causing-error-product-reorder-is-not-a-recognized-set-option)

Comment: That show your trigger issues. But I also think you should use a computed column: `ALTER TABLE ADD CPFValido AS (REPLACE(REPLACE(CPF,'.', ''),'-', ''))` Alternatively make a `CHECK` constraint to prevent incorrect data going in `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT CPFValido CHECK (CPF NOT LIKE '%.%' AND CPF NOT LIKE '%-%')`

Comment: @Charlieface comment is worthy of an answer